# Getting http post with basic authentication right in GO

Tags: http, go

I have a standard piece of go http request that I am trying to get right in the code below.

```
func IssueSearchQuery(conf Config) (string, error) {

    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }

    var client = &http.Client{
        Timeout:   time.Second * 60,
        Transport: tr,
    }
    URL := conf.URL + "/api/search"
    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("query_expression", "select * from test")
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", URL, 
        bytes.NewBufferString(v.Encode()))

    req.SetBasicAuth(conf.User, conf.Password)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    bodyText, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    s := string(bodyText)
    return s, err
}
```

In the above code, I am connecting to the server, basic authentication works, but the server responds  complaining saying the required `query_expression` query parameter is missing. If I do `curl -u user:pass -d "query_expression=select * from test" --insecure -XPOST 'https://ip:port/api/search'` the server responds with the required result.

The code also works if I don't use url.Values{} and instead manually encode my query into the url like `URL := conf.URL + "/api/ariel/searches?query_expression=select%20*20from%20test"`

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong with my query parameters. Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Does `req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` make a difference?

Comment: Jeez, that was it. I just set the content-type and it started working. So, in my version the server was getting a url-encoded query string, but was considering it as plain/text content-type?

Comment: Aside: you need to close response bodies when you're done with them, and consider using strings.NewReader instead of the buffer; "It is similar to bytes.NewBufferString but more efficient and read-only."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be trying to set the POST body to the url-encoded values.  Either set your `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and put them in the body as you're doing (thanks @hobbs), or use your url-encoded values in the actual url rather than the body:

```
u, err := url.Parse(conf.URL + "/api/search")
v := url.Values{}
v.Set("query_expression", "select * from test")
u.RawQuery = v.Encode()
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", u.String(), nil)
```

Typically people expect POST data to be in the body, so just adding the `req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` is probably the best.

Comment: Thanks a lot; adding the header fixed it for me.  Just for reference the code now looks like  ...`req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", URL, bytes.NewBufferString(v.Encode()))
 req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 req.SetBasicAuth(conf.QRadar.User, conf.QRadar.Password) `...